# Get CSS bg image from web page on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have the code of a web page and it contains lots of "divs" with backgroud images like this:

```
style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(/images/image1.jpg)"
```

Is there an easy way in VB.NET to get all the URLs from bg images from the page?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by getting the HTML by using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx#Y5802):

```
Dim client As New WebClient()

        ' Add a user agent header in case the 
        ' requested URI contains a query.
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")

        Dim data As Stream = client.OpenRead(args(0))
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(data)
        Dim s As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine(s)
        data.Close()
        reader.Close()
```

From here you can parse that string (s) looking for something that matches "BACKGROUDN-IMAGE: {*}" - someone else will need to chime in, my regex-fu is horrible. [Regex.Matches() - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)